# Why is my cardano-node not doing anything?

Tags: cardano-node, node

I've doubled my RAM to 16GB to be safe, and added a 4GB swap file as well, but when starting the node, it does this and then ... nothing else:

```
node-to-node versions:
NodeToNodeV_6   HardForkNodeToNodeEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToNodeVersion1 (EraNodeToNodeEnabled ByronNodeToNodeVersion2 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* EraNodeToNodeDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToNodeV_7   HardForkNodeToNodeEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToNodeVersion1 (EraNodeToNodeEnabled ByronNodeToNodeVersion2 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* EraNodeToNodeEnabled ShelleyNodeToNodeVersion1 :* Nil)
node-to-client versions:
NodeToClientV_1 HardForkNodeToClientDisabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1
NodeToClientV_2 HardForkNodeToClientDisabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1
NodeToClientV_3 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion1 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_4 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion2 :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_5 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion2 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion2 :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_6 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion2 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion2 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion2 :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_7 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion3 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion3 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion3 :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_8 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion3 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion3 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion3 :* EraNodeToClientDisabled :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_9 HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* Nil)
NodeToClientV_10    HardForkNodeToClientEnabled HardForkSpecificNodeToClientVersion2 (EraNodeToClientEnabled ByronNodeToClientVersion1 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* EraNodeToClientEnabled ShelleyNodeToClientVersion4 :* Nil)
```

When I ran `free -m` I get:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16008         195        1843           0       13968       15516
Swap:          4095           0        4095
```

Not sure if the database is corrupt and needs to be rebuilt, or what is going on. Is there a way to get a verbose error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your configuration file. This looks like your logs are going to a separate file. I've seen this with tools like cntools where they redirect all logging out of stdout into separate log files.